# keyboard shortcuts on parallels desktop running ubuntu

Tags: terminal, keyboard, unix, parallels-desktop

I am running: 
MacOS High Sierra on a 2016 TB MBP. >>
App: Parallels Desktop 12. >>
VM: Ubuntu Linux 16.04.

I only use the terminal of the Linux VM to communicate with robotic hardware.

When I use the terminal, I need to use generic Linux command line keyboard shortcuts.

This results in problems, to name a few:

-the cmd key shortcut cannot be disabled in the linux VM.
-all kinds of shortcuts such as ctrl-A, B, C, D, etc. result in actions that are not desired when using in a Linux Terminal.

I know that I can change the settings in the Parallels VM preferences, and within the system settings of the VM. However, nowhere I can find the most annoying shortcut of all, ctrl-D, that results in the following:

[image: result of ctrl-D shortcut when using the Linux terminal]

This shortcut, when running the MacOS, does not result in this dictation-like pictogram, so it is somehow a shortcut for either Parallels or Ubuntu.

My goal is to disable as many keyboard shortcuts as possible in the Linux VM/Parallels so that all the keyboard shortcuts are available for the Linux terminal command line.

Comment: Parallels has a key remap pref somewhere.. on phone right now & cant remember precisely where

Comment: It's in Preferences > Shortcuts. You should probably try Send System Shortcuts: Always.